# How to add AuthHeader on gowsdl

Tags: go, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am integrating soap service with use [gowsdl](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl) library.

I can't  create auth header like this;

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tem:AuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:UserName>?</tem:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Password>?</tem:Password>
      </tem:AuthHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using code generated by gowsdl

I will explain shortly;

AuthHeader in service.go

```
type AuthHeader struct {
    UserName string `xml:"UserName,omitempty" json:"UserName,omitempty"`

    Password string `xml:"Password,omitempty" json:"Password,omitempty"`
}
```

and I am using like this

```
authHeader := service.AuthHeader{
    Password: Password,
    UserName: Username,
}

header := struct {
    AuthHeader service.AuthHeader `xml:"AuthHeader,omitempty" json:"AuthHeader,omitempty"`
}{
    AuthHeader:authHeader,
}
```

And adding header like this;

```
soapClient := soap.NewClient(Url)

soapClient.AddHeader(header)
```

but it is not working! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Please show the code that you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how it is not working.

Comment: what is the exact error report back from the SOAP API?

Comment: Error expected element type <Envelope> but have <html> API returns html if authentication fails

Answer (score 0):

From  the [gowsdl](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl) package's [example.go](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl/blob/master/example/example.go) why not set the auth headers like so:

```
client := soap.NewClient(
        Url,
        soap.WithBasicAuth("usr", "psw"),
)
```

Comment: I did tried but doesn't work. I must bee add on header